# Encode ajax request data sent to a php page and then decode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I have a https request using ajax to external php page like in the code bweloow. Please note there are some strange non UTF-8 chars that have to be encoded, otherwise i would get a strange return.

```
//ajax request to external site
sometext = "I only wear Rtrtrr® shoes, and my name is Åron"; 

sometext = some_encoding(sometext); //a PSEUDO code line

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://targetsite.com/process_text.php",
    data: sometext,
    cache: false,
    success: function(proc_text) {
        alert()
    }
 });
```

On php page, then, I need to decode and use **some_decoding(sometext)** instead of **some_encoding(sometext)**.

Is there any way to encode such text, with **some_encoding** function i javascript that has analog function for some decoding in php.

For example **encodeURIComponent** doesn't convert all the chars, while **Base64** I used is not the same in PHP and Javascript in some cases. Is there something that is the same.

Comment: Won't have that problem if you use [utf-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Should i convert the text to utf-8?

Comment: and then decode it on return?

Comment: ajax uses utf-8 by default. Set page charset to utf-8 and db also and everything will flow smoothly with no encoding/decoding needed

Comment: The text is user input, I cant control it. My charset is UTF <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />, did you mean that. But still sometimes the request is is broken a bit.

Comment: probably because of how you store it in back end. Check the charset there